# Iterator wrong return type java

Tags: java, generics, iterator

I've got a problem with implementing defaul Iterator. My code looks like that:

```
import java.util.Iterator;


public class ProductIterator implements Iterator<Product> {

    private int index = 0;

    public boolean hasNext() {
        if (index < Product.getAllProducts().size()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public Product next() {
        if (hasNext()) {
            return Product.getAllProducts().get(index++);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Documentation says: Iterator works on elements E, and next() method returns E

but when I call it in code:

```
for (Iterator prodIter = getIterator(); prodIter.hasNext();) {
    Product product = prodIter.next();
    ...
}
```

i've got en error:

```
error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to Product
```

I'm little bit confused with that, cause it for shure should returns Product object.

Does anyone know why it isn't?

**SOLVED**

Changing all raw types into specific helps
thanks @Thomas

Comment: `getIterator()` should return `Iterator<Product>`.

Comment: Why don't you use `ProductIterator prodIter = getIterator()` or `Iterator<Product>` instead of the raw super type `Iterator`=

Comment: I am not so sure if "raw" type is really the "root" cause here. In any case, your question does **not** include a [mcve] methinks.

Comment: @GhostCat so, what type does a raw iterator's `next()` method return if not `Object`?

Comment: @AndyTurner Second thought ... guess you are right.

Comment: @BłażejPierzak Never put more information into comments. Always update your question instead.

Comment: What is the type of `Product.getAllProducts()`? It looks like it may be a `List` - can't you just use its iterator directly?

Comment: @Reimeus getIterator() method is written in the same class as called here as "public static Iterator<Product> getIterator()